# How can i get the Parent in Binary tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-tree

How can i get the Parent in Binary tree in this code ?

I wrote this :

```
public class Node
{
    public string state;
    public Node Left;
    public Node Right;




    public Node (string s , Node L , Node R )
    {
        this.state = s;
        this.Right = R;
        this.Left = L;
    }

    public Node (string s)
    {
        this.state = s;
        this.Right = null;
        this.Left = null;
    }


}
```

And code this for tree of some data  :

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHbjR.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljVjb.png)

Now , how can i get the parent of Node like ( new Node("22lltrk", null, null) ) 
what i need to add to my code and where ?

thanks .

Comment: Please show what code you tried in order to solve your problem. Showing just initialization data of the tree isn't relevant code

Comment: Found this on first search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736577/find-the-parent-node-of-a-node-in-binary-search-tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opt 1: add a parent link to your class

```
public class Node 
{
    public string state;
    public Node Left;
    public Node Right;
    public Node Parent; // new

    public Node (string s , Node L , Node R )
    {
        this.state = s;
        this.Right = R;
        this.Right.Parent = this; // new
        this.Left = L;
        this.Left.Parent = this; // new
    }

    public Node (string s)
    {
        this.state = s;
        this.Right = null;
        this.Left = null;
        this.Parent = null; // new
    }
}
```

Opt 2: Tree traversal

```
Node FindParent(Node root, Node child)
{
   // Base Cases
   if(root.Left == null && root.Right == null)
    return null;

   if(root.Left == child || root.Right == child)
    return root;

   // Recursion
   var leftSearch = FindParent(root.Left, child);
   if (leftSearch != null)
       return leftSearch;

   return FindParent(root.Right, child);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation