# Finding successor and predecessor in bst in O(1)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Is there a way to add some information to nodes in a bst while inserting or deleting them. So that it is possible to get the successor and predecessor in O(1).

Comment: You could perhaps use a sorted array instead of a tree.

Comment: You could add pointers to the successor and predecessor to each node.

Comment: It has to be a tree.

Comment: You can have 2 additional node attributes as predecessor and successor and edit them whenever adding a new node while perlocating down. So, time complexity for a successor or a predecessor is O(1)?

Answer (score 2):

If in each node you also store the reference to the parent, then you can see how you would be able to find the next node, given a node:

```py
getNext(node):
    if node.right is not null:
        node = node.right
        while node.left is not null:
            node = node.left
        return node
    while node.parent is not null:
        if node.parent.left == node:  # node is a left child
            return node.parent
        node = node.parent  # node was a right child
    # no more nodes...
    return null
```

As you see, there are loops involved, so this takes a varying time. In the worst case, the node that follows a leaf may be the root, and the node following the root may be a deep leaf. So one call may involve up to *h* reassignments to `node`, following that many edges in the tree (*h* is the height of the tree).

But if you consider a complete traversal over all nodes, starting at the left-most leaf, you see that each edge is traversed exactly 2 times: first with either `left` or `right`, and second with `parent`. Except for the edges on the path from the root to the left-most leaf: those are only visited once, with `parent`. But for simplicity, let's just say they are also visited twice (we over-estimate the work slightly).

That means that for the *n* calls to `getNext` (where the previous result is fed into the next call and the last call returns `null`), you would visit *2(n-1)* edges, meaning that on average one call traverses *2(n-1)/n* edges, which is always (slightly) less than 2.

Therefore this represents an amortised *O(1)* time complexity.

Of course, the algorithm for `getPrevious` would be similar and have the same time complexity considerations.

The algorithms for insert and delete operations (including rotations in self-balancing trees) can be easily extended to also update the `parent` reference in each involved node without increasing the time complexity.

Comment: Upvoted. A doubly threaded binary tree is a good alternative if amortised O(1) is needed, since it only uses 1 extra bit per node.

Comment: How do you implement a doubly threaded binary tree. I searched for it but found nothing realy suitable. I tried to do it but sometimes nodes have to update but they dont.

Comment: If you have a specific implementation problem, then please ask a new question about it, providing your code, the problem it has, the expected behaviour, ...etc. There should be several implementations you can find here, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43774781/5459839). Of course, it depends on the kind of interface you expect, and programming language.